# can not connect to postgreSQL database on heroku from herokuCLI

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I try to connect using following command but it's hanging there .( PATH environment variable added)

```
$ heroku pg:psql <databasename>
--> Connecting to <databasename>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am currently on the phone right so basically look at this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) first.

Now in Heroku go and check first if you have an ads on `PostgreSQL` if not then create it first on the website but if you really want it on CLI here is how you can do it

`heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:<PLAN_NAME>`

for example : `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`

Now check if you have already created the `hobby-dev`like this

`heroku addons`

**#DID NOT SETUP YET**

Remember to update your PATH environment variable to add the bin directory of your Postgres installation. The directory will be similar to this: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL<VERSION>\bin. If you forget to update your PATH, commands like heroku pg:psql won’t work.

Here's the link of the [Installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)

The psql client will typically be installed in `/usr/bin:`
or you could check it out by yourself

`which psql`

and the command should work correctly: `psql`

PS: MAYBE YOURS ISN'T WORKING BECAUSE YOU DIDN'T INSTALL POSTGRESQL PROPERLY KINDLY CHECK IT

Comment: Tnxs for the help when i run it with cmd it worked . But with git bash it didn't worked. Can you explain what can be wrong with git bash.

Comment: what exactly is not working on gitbash?? because when using gitbash you must always point out where your project is first.